# jQuery delete text on input after submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I putted a jQuery script on my chat so the message sends without page refreshing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#msgsending").validate({
               type: "POST",
                    debug: false,

                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                            // do other stuff for a valid form
                            $.post('index.php', $("#msgsending").serialize(), function(data) {

                            });
                    }
            });
    });
    </script>
```

And form

```
 <form id="msgsending" name="form" method="post" action="" > 
<input name="message" id="message" type="text" maxlength="350" />

<input name="message" id="message" type="text" maxlength="350" />

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send!" />

</form>
```

The code works perfectly. (index is the script that insert the message + username in the database)

But now I have a issue.

The text don't delete on the message input after submitting.
I've google'd alot of pages and all the codes didn't work. (Somes worked but message isn't sending)

What do you recommand me?

Comment: You are using `id=message`on two inputs. jQuery assumes only one element with that id, mening that it only accesses the first.

Comment: I'm actually only using one. But I accidently putted two while writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#message').val('');` should clear the `input`'s value, and I'm guessing you'd do this after the message was sent, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#msgsending").validate({
       type: "POST",
          debug: false,
          submitHandler: function(form) {
               // do other stuff for a valid form
               $.post('index.php', $("#msgsending").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#message').val('');
               });
          }
    });
});
```

This will only work on the first element with the `ID` `#message`, as `ID`'s are unique and you can't have two elements with the same `ID`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a beginner at jQuery and I didn't though of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$.post('index.php', $("#msgsending").serialize(), function(data) {

});
```

you could do something like:

```
var data = $("#msgsending").serialize();
$('#message').val('');

$.post('index.php', data, function(data) {

});
```

to empty the message field *before* sending the request OR as @adeneo suggest, you can empty the field in the success callback of the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can place any code within the callback function of `.post()` in order to clear out or reset the form.

You also have `type: "POST"` listed as an option for `.validate()`.  You should remove this as it's [not a valid option/parameter for this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Since you're doing ajax, you'll need a `return false` at the end of your `submitHandler` in order to prevent a page redirection.

Optionally, you can also replace `$('#msgsending').serialize()` with `$(form).serialize()` or `form.serialize()` since `form` is passed into the `submitHandler` callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#msgsending").validate({
        type: "POST", // <-- REMOVE THIS... not a valid plugin option
        debug: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('index.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#message').val(''); // clears out #message
                // any other code to clear out or reset the form
            });
            return false; // prevent page redirection
        }
    });
});
```